# How to catch a key press on a C# .NET form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a parent form that contains a lot of controls.  What I am trying to do is filter all of the key presses for that form.  The trouble is that if the focus is on one of the controls on the form then the parent form is not getting the key press event, so how do I capture the key down event?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Set KeyPreview to true on your form and you will catch them: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: What is absolutely amazing with micro$oft, is that the boolean is called KeyPreview but you have to use Form_KeyDown to intercept the key, not Form_PreviewKeyDown.

Answer (score 8):

This will only work on form, but not if any other component is in focus

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{

    public ChildForm()
    {       
       KeyPress += KeyPressHandler;
    }

    public KeyPressHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       if (_parent != null)
       {
           _parent.NotifyKeyPress(e);
       } 
    }
}
```

This will work even when other components are in focus

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the F1 key");
        return true;    // indicate that you handled this keystroke
    }

    // Call the base class
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```