# is there any way to check what Keys pressed from anywhere of Windows Form ?

Tags: c#

is there any way to check what keys pressed from anywhere of Windows form?
I have tried make it with Events(KeyDown)

```
if(e.KeyCode==Keys.F5)
{
    search();
}
if(e.KeyCode==Keys.F2)
{
    save();
} // and more ...
```

But i want know is there any easy way to check what keys is pressed from any where of Windows form?
It's take time to make all objects Events(KeyDown).

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  Something else?  Add an appropriate tag for your UI framework.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3001264/20126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into overriding [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In my opinion it's better than setting KeyPreview on your form, and definitely beats setting a handler for every single control.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case /* whatever key combination */:
        // do something
        default:
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a static class, for example - KeyboardHelper.

In that class create an event handler

```
public KeyPressed(object sender, arguments)
{
}
```

and in each form/control etc. constructor do this:

```
this.KeyDown += KeyboardHelper.KeyPressed;
```

and all of your events will sink to one function - in keyboard manager class.

Also you could look into - event bubbling and tunneling and how it is in C#.