# Draw pixels by using the letters a-z

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to draw a pixel on a specific place in my form when I press a specific key in my keyboard.
how can I do that?
here's a snippet code from my project:

```
 private void paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

     int x = 5, y = 5;
     e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(55, 55, x, y));}
```

Comment: Handling the key press would be a first step (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001237/how-to-catch-a-key-press-on-a-c-sharp-net-form). See if you can then call your method from that and, if not, post the updated code

Comment: this is the code i am working on:
'private void press(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, PaintEventArgs g)
 int x = 5, y = 5; if (e.KeyValue <'a' && e.KeyValue <= 'z'){
 MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
 e.KeyValue.ToString() + "' pressed.");
 switch (e.KeyValue) {
  case (char) 'a':
    g.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(55, 55, x, y));
 break; case (char)'b': case (char)'c':
MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" +
 e.KeyValue.ToString() + "' consumed.");
 e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                }
            }'
@keyboardP

Comment: Edit your question to add code. Do not add it in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm a little rusty to winforms, but I think you should try this:

1. Select the main form, go to the properties window, go to the events part of the properties window, and click "KeyDown."
2. In the KeyDown method, put in this:

   ```
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
       {
           Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
           Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
           Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

           int x = 5;
           int y = 5;
           g.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, 55, 55);
       }
   ```

VOILA!

Comment: Bad advice to use `CreateGraphics()`.  It's volatile.  Painting should _always_ be done in a proper `Paint` event.

Comment: @DonBoitnott is right.  Anything drawn with this method will be erased if the form is repainted or if a window crosses in front of it.  Also, the `Graphics` instance you get from `CreateGraphics` may not be the same as the one you get in the `OnPaint` override.  The on in `OnPaint`  might different if the form is double buffered, for example.