# Not getting spacebar input

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want a variable to be incremented when I press the spacebar.
This is what I have tried so far, and it doesn't seem to be working. There's no error message, so I don't know what is wrong.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int Coins = 0;
    int ButtonKeyNumber = (int)Key.Space;

    private void textBlockCoins_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == ButtonKeyNumber)
        {
            Coins = Coins + 1;
            textBlockCoins.Text = "You Have " + Coins + "Coins";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the textbox just says "You Have 0 Coins".
The variable ButtonKeyNumber is there because I want to be able to easily change which key will need to be pressed.

Comment: Why do you need the variable at all? Compare directly to `Key.Space`, and then use the debugger to figure out what key you're getting in `e.KeyValue`.

Comment: Is your KeyDown event callback actually being called?  Make sure that the correct control has focus (first, click on textBlockCoins) to receive the KeyDown event.  Put a breakpoint on the `if` and see what the value of e.KeyValue actually is!

Comment: did `textBlockCoins_KeyDown` trigger ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using the wrong `Keys` class.  Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` class, this is the type that is provided by `KeyEventArgs.KeyCode`. Try something like this instead.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int Coins = 0;
    Keys CoinKey = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Space;

    private void textBlockCoins_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == CoinKey)
        {
            Coins = Coins + 1;
            textBlockCoins.Text = "You Have " + Coins + "Coins";
        }
    }
}
```

You still have to make sure the right control has focus when hitting the space key.

Answer (score 0):

Set KeyPreview to true on your form and you will catch them: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(VS.71).aspx)

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001264/4846465)